# How can I find the targeting url of a request logged for a Spring boot service

Tags: java, spring, logging

I am using Spring boot 2.0.5, and I got below log in the console:

```
  2019-10-12 13:27:49.577  WARN 45639 --- [io-65533-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [ongframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

Questions:

1. How can I know that which url this get request is targeting?
2. Where can I learn the meaning of each field in this log line, i.e.: `45639`, `io-65533-exec-5`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` class from Spring.

From [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE_to_3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html) :

> A builder for `UriComponents` that offers static factory methods to
>   extract information from an `HttpServletRequest`.

You have to log the request in every method entry point.

For example :

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    public final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class);

    @GetMapping("/")    
    public void someMethod() {
      LOGGER.debug(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().toUriString());
      // rest of the code.
    }

}
```

Or you can implement `Spring-AOP` to log every call (that's a better approach of logging since it's a centralized logging).

Comment: @ZhaoGang Yes !!